# Display latency using OpenGL Quad Buffer with nvidia stereoscopic 3D

Tags: opengl, 3d

I need to achieve real-time performance (60fps) with my stereoscopic 3D application in c++ for video rendering, using OpenGL Quad Buffer. The application runs on Xubuntu Lts 14.04.
My hardware setup is composed by two Gopro cameras, a nvidia quadro k4000 card and a 120Hz display.

I'm experiencing image latency when watching the displayed stereo video. 
There is no important delay when displaying only from one camera, in a mono setup, while not using the quad buffer functionality.

When measuring the times of execution of the display function from OpenGL it takes less than 10 mseconds to execute on most cycles, but there are spikes of more than 60ms that are probably the origin of such latency.

I've tested both with and without setting the sync to vblank option on the graphic's card, and the difference is very little, resulting in the same delayed image on the screen.

The code bellow is part of a more complex application so I hope the parts I provide at least shed a light on what I am trying to accomplish.

EDIT 1: This is the initialization code, outside the display function.

```
createTexture(&textureID, width, height);

createPBO(&pbo, width, height);

// map OpenGL buffer object for writing from CUDA
cudaGLMapBufferObject((void **)(Img, pbo);

// Unmap Buffers
cudaGLUnmapBufferObject(pbo);

// Paths for the stereo shaders' files
const std::string vertex_file_path = "VertexShader_stereo.vertexshader";
const std::string fragment_file_path = "FragmentShader_stereo.fragmentshader";

GLfloat vertices [] = {
    // Position (2 elements) Texcoords (2 elements)
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // Top-left
    1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // Top-right
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
  };

GLushort elements [] = {
    0, 1, 2, // indices of the first triangle
    2, 3, 0  // indices of the second triangle
  };

// Create a pixel buffer object for the right view
createPBO(&pbo_Right, width, height);

// map OpenGL buffer object for writing from CUDA
cudaGLMapBufferObject((void **)Img_Right, pbo_Right);

// Unmap Buffers
cudaGLUnmapBufferObject(pbo_Right);

// Create a vector buffer object
createVBO(&vbo, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
// Create a element buffer object
createEBO(&ebo, elements, sizeof(elements));

// Create shader program from the shaders
shaderProgram = LoadShader(vertex_file_path, fragment_file_path);

posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texcoord");
}
```

Edit 2: The createPBO function goes like this:

```
createPBO(GLuint* pbo_, unsigned int w, unsigned int h) {
        // set up vertex data parameter
        int num_texels = w * h;
        int num_values = num_texels * 4;
        int size_tex_data = sizeof(GLubyte) * num_values;

        // Generate a buffer ID called a PBO (Pixel Buffer Object)
        glGenBuffers(1, pbo_);
        // Make this the current UNPACK buffer (OpenGL is state-based)
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, *pbo_);
        // Allocate data for the buffer. 4-channel 8-bit image
        glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, size_tex_data, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
        cudaGLRegisterBufferObject(*pbo_);
}
```

Bellow is the part of my display function related to the OpenGL environment. I am using several glFinish() calls as an experiment, since it seems to be enhancing the execution times.

```
// Make this the current array buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

// Make this the current element array buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);

// Activate shader program
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

// Specify the layout of the vertex data
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib,           // index of of attribute in array
                      2,                   // size
                      GL_FLOAT,            // type
                      GL_FALSE,            // normalized
                      4 * sizeof(GLfloat), // stride 
                      0);                  // offset in the array

glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib,                     // index of of attribute in array
                      2,                             // size
                      GL_FLOAT,                      // type
                      GL_FALSE,                      // normalized
                      4* sizeof(GLfloat),            // stride 
                      (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat))); // offset in the array


glFinish();

// Specifies the target to which the buffer object is bound. GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER affects the glTexSubImage2D command.
glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);
// Draw Left Back Buffer
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);

// Specifies the target (GL_TEXTURE_2D) to which the texture is bound
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

// Note: NULL indicates the data resides in device memory
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
// Draw a rectangle from the 2 triangles using 6 indices
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

// Specifies the target to which the buffer object is bound. GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER affects the glTexSubImage2D command.
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo_Right);
// Draw Right Back Buffer
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT);

// Note: NULL indicates the data resides in device memory
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
// Draw a rectangle from the 2 triangles using 6 indices
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0); 

glFinish();

// Disable and unbind objects
glDisableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
glUseProgram(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// Swap buffers
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
```

It is possible to make some optimizations? or is this a known problem in stereoscopic 3D?

Comment: It is not yet clear where the performance bottleneck is in your setup and code. How do you upload the data into the PBO in the first place? You might be able to improve perofrmance by explicitely oprhaning the PBO before storing the new frame (if you don't do that already) or using a ring buffer of PBOs. You definitively shouldn't use the `glFinish()` calls in the way you use them currently.

Comment: I've added the initialization code. The data is already in the GPU, as it is processed by CUDA. I am not familiar with the concept of oprhaning the PBO, can you further explain.

Comment: Well, even if you write to the buffer by GL-cuda-interop, y0u have to update the data somehow in the loop, and synchornize between CUDA and the GL. For buffer orphaning, have a look at [this opengl wiki link](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming#Server-side_multi-buffering_.28buffer_re-specification.2Forphaning.29)

Comment: @Edien: You know that you can map OpenGL textures into CUDA as well. By using a ring of textures you can safe that extra data duplication done by glTexSubImage2D.

Comment: I've been reading about the ring buffer of PBOs but this is not very clear to me: defining several pbos and alternating between them on write and reading. Can anyone explain me how the concept works in practice?